# Product Images not shown after uploading , how?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1

I am having a very strange problem, i am uploading product images through admin panel but when i upload image it shows 100% uploaded but doesn't show image row at all . Tried so many things but couldn't make it work.

Please help if anybody know about this problem[image]

I have tried giving permissions 777 to media folder but it doesn't work for me. This happens when i uploaded the site on server, when it was on my local machine it was working fine.

Comment: Would make sense to mention what have you tried. What about writing permissions?

Comment: Could be browser related problem. Try different browser.

Comment: It's not a browser problem i have checked it on other browsers also. same problem exist there too

Comment: Hello Tim i tried to give permission 777 to media folder but it's not working.

Comment: Did you set permissions only to media dir or to all subdirs recursively?

Comment: Hello Tim i set it recursively

Comment: Remove cache and re-indexing data.

Comment: Please check you have enabled curl and gd libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was due to missing gd library on server.

Answer (score 1):

Hook into a http sniffer. It looks like a php error, therefore the flash uploader can't parse the response message. Therefore nothing happens and the uploader doesn't call the javascript functions to add the row to the table, etc.

Comment: hello fabian ,, i also want to tell you that i checked the media folder images are not getting uploaded and this is happening for the the whole site. i can not upload images at all

Comment: Great. Have a look into the request and you will see your problem - hopefully

Comment: Hello fabian i just downloaded the whole site and ran onto my localhost it just worked fine. so i think there is something related to server, any clue ??

Comment: Did you check the HTTP response from the server for the flash?

Comment: Hello Fabian sorry but i am not getting you, how should i check when i use firebug console it shows no request at all.

Comment: Correct. The problem is, the request is made by the Flash applet, therefore you don't see the request in firebug or any other firefox extension (maybe in FlashBug/debugger). I use for this HTTPScoop http://www.tuffcode.com/ - it only works with HTTP(!) You can use wireshark or fiddler, too.

Comment: `sudo tcpdump -i <interface> -X "tcp port 80"` use this to sniff your HTTP traffic and check for error messages. Also consult the webserver error logs on your server.